# android.view.InflateException Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, picasso

This issue seems to only occur on a small number of devices but crashes the entire app for those users.

The app loads two images at once, one is the original, one is a blurred copy for a scrolling effect. I'm  now using Picasso to load in images which reduced the issues but this still occurs for a select few.

A new set of images (original & blurred) is loaded every time the app is opened.

The images are initialised in the onCreateView method as follows:

```
    nonBlurImageView = (ImageView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.orginal_image);
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(getResources().getIdentifier(bgNum, "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName())).into(nonBlurImageView);

    blurredImageView = (ImageView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.blured_image);
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(getResources().getIdentifier(bgNum+"_blur", "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName())).into(blurredImageView);
```

The stack trace starts with

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
```

Where #24 is

```
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/orginal_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_1" />
```

Is there an issue with GC or something? Is there a better way I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think `@drawable/bg_1` is too large, decode it and then assign it programmatically.

Comment: What do you mean by decoding it? Just remove it as the default src?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty late though, but may someone stumble upon here. I had nearly the same issue that my app crashes on start because it try's to load an empty `String` into an `ImageView`. Empty strings throw an Exception inside the `Piccasso.load()` method, but `null` doesn't. `null` loads the placeholder instead.

So try to check your url  first if its empty or your image ressource id equals zero and if so use `null` instead of ""/0.

hope this will help even if its late :D